# Creating an OSM map app with React native and Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapbox, openstreetmap, expo

i need a hint... started in React native and tried Expo. Goal is to create an OSM map app for hiking. So far i run into 2 problems:

- no background works in Expo location
- no OSM map plugin compatible with Expo

First might be resolved in the future, the Expo guys work on that. 
Second... using something like the mapbox for JS will not help, as i did not see any solution for offline caching.

Now i am asking myself if i should continue without Expo using pure React native (mapbox SDK will offer caching), or keep Expo and create a map-box on my own (loading tiles based on lat/lon and displaying the current position on a tile is not that hard...)

Any experiences for a similar problem?

As this is kind of a learning project i am not interested in available apps, i am already using some of them ;)

Thanks and regards, Jo

Comment: are u solve it?

Comment: i created a working example with my own map solution: https://github.com/wende60/hiker 
Still in progress...